# Installing Marketo Sales Insight app in Developer Edition org

Tags: app-development

I'm trying to install the Marketo Sales Insight app in my Developer Edition org but it's asking for a password. I did not receive any email. Anybody knows what the password should be?

I just installed the Marketo Lead Management App and that worked without problems...

**Additional info in response to JLiljegren__c's comment:**

The password request appears after you've logged in with your Salesforce credentials. Screenshot below. Any additional installation steps could only be done after installing the app.

I tried contacting Marketo, but their sales people tells you to talk to support, and support cannot be reached either by phone or by email if your phone or email are not in their contacts database (they literally send you an email back saying "[...]The email address used to submit this case was not recognized as an Authorized Support Contact[...]"). The app was installed in production by the client, so they are the authorized contact.

This is where it asks for the password:

[image]

It tells you that you can install it for free in a dev org but then it doesn't give you any way to complete the installation process...

[image]

All this comes from the fact that the client has the Marketo Sales Insight app running in production and I'm trying to install it in a dev org some I can do some additional work for this client (we have more than one dev in the project and we want each to have its own dev environment). I cannot deploy from my local project (which I pulled from the Sandbox) to the dev org where I want to develop because the installed packages break the build.

Comment: Please add some more context to your question. In which stage of the installation is it asking for a password? As you say you've installed another app I assume it's not the usual SFDC username and password for your org? Any screenshots of the page in question would help. Have you been in contact with Marketo? Have you read the installation guide, if there is one?

Comment: When I try installing it in my DE Org, it gives me a warning - "This app does not list support for your edition of Salesforce. You can continue installation, but it may fail later in the process." Did you get the same ? I get the same error as you have described in your screenshot when I chose to ignore the Warning and continue. I would think its not supported on a Dev Edition Org?

Comment: I did, but I went ahead because I figured it's because the Dev Org is in version Winter 13, which the app may not been yet tested against. But I don't think you can create a dev org in a previous version, can you? In any case, I was able to install the Market Lead Management app in the dev org without problems (and without being asked for a password) even though I also got that warning.

Comment: In the install button it says "Includes active, trial or **developer** orgs". (I added the screenshot to the description.)

Comment: That is odd indeed, one for Marketo Support.

Comment: Does your client have a contract with Marketo? If they're validating email addresses sending to support (which, to me, sounds pretty obscure) could you have the person on the contract send the question to them?

Comment: Yeah, it's crazy, specially for a company specialized in marketing, that you cannot reach them by either phone or by email with support questions unless your phone or email is registered with them. Anyway, we've decided that we will all work with the same Sandbox. Let's see how that goes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: They finally got back to me. I got an email from a sales associate. After describing the problem he sent me another email with a link to a support article that I cannot access because I don't have a Marketo account. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to get this password from a contact at Marketo. Was accepted by SalesForce without a problem.

Now I just need to figure out how to install & setup the app. Can't seem to find documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can find required password in the "Get started" article. https://community.marketo.com/MarketoArticle?id=kA050000000KywCCAS

Answer (score 0):

Marketo has some basic documentation (you will have to log in to your Marketo account to view it).

Getting started with Sales Insight:
https://community.marketo.com/MarketoArticle?id=kA050000000KywCCAS

Request Campaign and Campaign is Requested:
https://community.marketo.com/MarketoArticle?id=kA050000000Kytx

However, it's out of date and poorly written. Does anyone else know of any better documentation?